# How can I make this program read the entire file before returning value false?

Tags: java

I have a GUI asking for a word, and when the word isn't found it returns not found for every word within dictionary.txt. I'm assuming some sort of array will be used to increment every false, but I don't know exactly how to write something like that. I can see why it returns "Nothing matches" for every incorrect string. Any suggestions?

```
            File file = new File("dictionary.txt"); 
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);
            inputFile.useDelimiter("\n");

            String wordCheck = textField.getText();

            while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
                String dictWord = inputFile.next();
                if (wordCheck.equals(dictWord)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pie for you!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nothing matches");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store result of `wordCheck.equals(dictWord)` in boolean variable and decide what to show after reading whole file and yes remove `break;` satement.

```
boolea isValid = false;
while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
 ...
  if (wordCheck.equals(dictWord)) {
    isValid = true;
  }
}

if (isValid)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pie for you!");
} else {
     System.out.println("Nothing matches");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `boolean found = false;` before your while loop and set `found = true;` inside the loop if you found something (instead of showing the message). Then display the message AFTER the loop, depending on the state of your `found` variable.